# Save checkbox on/off value - Laravel

Tags: laravel

One of my form fields needs to be able to save a boolean value from a checkbox field. Checked = true, uncheck = false. How do I set my input field?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="user_private_account" @if($usersetting->user_private_account == true) checked @endif >
```

Comment: You just want to show checked  selected? name is missing in your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="user_private_account" @if($usersetting->user_private_account == true) checked @endif name="user_private_account">
```

In your Contoller

```
 $object->required = $request->user_private_account ? 1 : 0;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Do simple:

```
$object->required = isset($request->user_private_account)
```

Because `isset()` will return only `true` or `false`.